# Query Year over Year Results on Items and Their Events

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement which queries if an item exists within a year:

```
SELECT 
    t.item_type_code,
    t.item_id
FROM   
    ITEM_TABLE t
WHERE
    extract(year from t.issue_date) =< 2022 AND
    extract(year from t.termination_date) => 2022
```

I now want to look at some events that occurred on the items. I would like a count of events that occurred on the item for each year it existed.

**In other words:**

1. Query the items that existed in a given year
2. Get a count of events that occurred on those items in that given year.

The following query returns that information:

```
WITH items AS
(      
    SELECT 
        t.item_type,
        t.item_id
    FROM   
        ITEM_TABLE t
    WHERE
        extract(year from t.issue_date) <= 2022 AND
        extract(year from t.termination_date) => 2022
)
SELECT
    t.item_type,
    COUNT(event_id)
FROM
    items t 
INNER JOIN
    events_xref x ON t.item_id = x.item_id
INNER JOIN
    events ON x.event_id = e.event_id
WHERE
    extract(year from e.effective_date) = 2022
GROUP BY
    t.item_type
```

What I would like to do is not hard code the years. I'd like to the query to iterate over each year and return the same information. Can someone suggest how to do that?

**EDIT**

I've been asked to clarify more. So, say your job is to issue drivers licenses. Each license has a lifespan, from the time it gets issued until it expires. Further to that, a license can have a number of events recorded against it over time. For example, the issuance is an event. A speeding ticket (or any other infraction) is an event. The expiry of a license is an event, etc.

The `item` table contains information about the license. The ID, the issue date and the expiry date

The `event` table stores the events that occurred on each license including the `event_id`, event type and event date.

The `events_xref` table is just used as a cross-reference table to join the above 2 tables and only contains the `item_id` and `event_id`.

What I have been asked to provide is:

1. First, collect a list of all the licenses that existed in a given year (i.e. if its issue_date was in or before that year and it's expiry_date was in or after that year)
2. take that list and get a count of all the events that occurred on the list in that same given year
3. I need to report back over the last 75 or so year, so I need to do the same for each year.

The query I provided does exactly what I need, but I have to rerun it and change the year in the 3 locations you see in the query each time to get data for the last 75. I was hoping to have the query handle that.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the problem; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment it is difficult to follow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not sure why you would vote to close my question. I am attempting to do my best to explain a legitimate query question. I don't mind adding additional information if I have missed something, which I just have.

Comment: The additional information needed is in the previous comment. `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and details of the output you expect for that sample data. Your sample data should include any edge cases that need to be considered and the explanation should explain the logic of how you get from the input data to the output data.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to use a row generator to generate the years and then `GROUP BY` the year as well as the `item_type`:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM y.year) AS year,
       t.item_type,
       COUNT(e.event_id)
FROM   ( SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, YY), 12 * (1 - LEVEL))
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 75
       ) y
       INNER JOIN item_table t
       ON     t.issue_date       <  ADD_MONTHS(y.year, 12)
          AND t.termination_date >= y.year
       INNER JOIN events_xref x
       ON t.item_id = x.item_id
       INNER JOIN events e
       ON x.event_id = e.event_id
GROUP BY
       t.item_type,
       y.year;
```

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear, @MT0 and I always appreciate peoples time and effort to help me on Stack. I've added more information and I am hoping that clarifies things more. The query I am being asked to create has a 2 step process. Get the items that active in a given year and then take that list and count all the events that occurred on those items in the same year. Have a look at my edit. If it's still not clear, I'll retry.

Comment: @Mike The answer has been updated but we are still mostly guessing as to your requirements. What would really make it clear is if the [question was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77290621/edit) to include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data (so we can easily replicate the problem) and then the expected output for that sample data (with an English, not code, explanation of why that output is generated).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell that I got it right, but maybe I could help with the hard-coded years mention as an issue. Let's generate some dummy sample data first ...
...items

```sql
WITH        -- S a m p l e    D a t a 
    items AS
        (   Select  '2000_' || To_Char(LEVEL) "ID", 
                    To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 2, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(1999 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ISSUE_DATE",
                    ADD_MONTHS(To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 2, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(1999 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 12) - 1 "EXPIRY_DATE"
            From    Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 2
          UNION ALL
            Select  '2001_' || To_Char(LEVEL) "ID", 
                    To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 3, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD(LEVEL  + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(2000 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ISSUE_DATE",
                    ADD_MONTHS(To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 2, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(2000 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 12) - 1 "EXPIRY_DATE"
            From    Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 4
          UNION ALL
            Select  '2002_' || To_Char(LEVEL) "ID", 
                    To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 6, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(2001 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ISSUE_DATE",
                    ADD_MONTHS(To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 2, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(2001 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 12) - 1 "EXPIRY_DATE"
            From    Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 3
        ),
--
--      I t e m s
--  ID        ISSUE_DATE EXPIRY_DATE
--  --------- ---------- -----------
--  2000_1    02-JAN-00  01-JAN-01
--  2000_2    03-FEB-01  02-FEB-02
--  2001_1    03-FEB-01  01-JAN-02
--  2001_2    04-MAR-02  02-FEB-03
--  2001_3    05-APR-03  03-MAR-04
--  2001_4    06-MAY-04  04-APR-05
--  2002_1    06-JAN-02  01-JAN-03
--  2002_2    07-FEB-03  02-FEB-04
--  2002_3    08-MAR-04  03-MAR-05
--
```

...events

```sql
    events AS
        (   Select  100 + LEVEL "EVENT_ID", SubStr('ABCDEF', CEIL(LEVEL * 3 / 2), 1) "EVENT_TYPE",
                    ADD_MONTHS(To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 2, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(1999 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 3) + (7 * LEVEL) "EVENT_DATE"
            From    Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 4
    UNION ALL
      Select    200 + LEVEL "EVENT_ID", SubStr('ABCDEF', CEIL(LEVEL * 2 / 3), 1) "EVENT_TYPE",
                    To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 2, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(2000 + LEVEL), 'dd.mm.yyyy') + LEVEL "EVENT_DATE"
            From    Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 4
    UNION ALL
      Select    300 + LEVEL "EVENT_ID", SubStr('ABCDEF', CEIL(LEVEL * 2 / 3), 1) "EVENT_TYPE",
                    To_Date(LPAD((LEVEL  - 1) + 1, 2, 0) || '.' || LPAD(LEVEL, 2, 0) || '.' || To_Char(2001 + LEVEL  - 1), 'dd.mm.yyyy') - (2 * LEVEL) "EVENT_DATE"
            From    Dual
            Connect By LEVEL <= 3
        ),
--
--      E v e n t s
--    EVENT_ID EVENT_TYPE EVENT_DATE
--  ---------- ---------- ---------
--         101 B          09-APR-00
--         102 C          17-MAY-01
--         103 E          25-JUN-02
--         104 F          02-AUG-03
--         201 A          03-JAN-01
--         202 B          05-FEB-02
--         203 B          07-MAR-03
--         204 C          09-APR-04
--         301 A          30-DEC-00
--         302 B          29-JAN-02
--         303 B          25-FEB-03
--
```

...xref

```sql
    xref AS
        (   Select  '2000_1' "ITEM_ID", 101 "EVENT_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select  '2000_1', 301 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2000_2', 102 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2001_1', 201 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2001_1', 302 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2001_2', 103 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2001_3', 104 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2002_1', 202 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2002_2', 203 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2002_2', 303 From Dual Union All
            Select  '2002_3', 204 From Dual Union All
        )
--
--      X r e f
--  ITEM_ID   EVENT_ID
--  ------  ----------
--  2000_1         101
--  2000_1         301
--  2000_2         102
--  2001_1         201
--  2001_1         302
--  2001_2         103
--  2001_3         104
--  2002_1         202
--  2002_2         203
--  2002_2         303
--  2002_3         204
```

Now you could create CTE with the years present in your items table to be used later in order to avoid hard-coding

```sql
    years AS
        (   Select      Min(Extract(YEAR From ISSUE_DATE)) + LEVEL - 1 "A_YEAR"
            From        items 
            Group By    LEVEL
            Connect By  LEVEL <= ( Select Max(Extract(YEAR From EXPIRY_DATE)) - Min(EXTRACT(YEAR From ISSUE_DATE)) + 1 From items )
            Order By    LEVEL
        )
--
--      Y e a r s
--      A_YEAR
--  ----------
--        2000
--        2001
--        2002
--        2003
--        2004
--        2005
```

With this you could get yearly items and count of events without hard-coded years. Maybe something like below or something else adjusted to your actual context and needs.

```sql
--      M a i n    S Q L
Select      y.A_YEAR,
            i.ID "ITEM_ID",
            Count(e.EVENT_ID) "ITEM_EVENTS_PER_YEAR"
From        years y
Inner Join  items i ON( y.A_YEAR = Extract(YEAR From i.ISSUE_DATE) Or y.A_YEAR = Extract(YEAR From i.EXPIRY_DATE) )
Inner Join  xref x ON(x.ITEM_ID = i.ID)
Inner Join  events e ON(e.EVENT_ID = x.EVENT_ID And Extract(YEAR From i.ISSUE_DATE) = y.A_YEAR)
Group By    y.A_YEAR, i.ID
Having      Count(e.EVENT_ID) > 0
Order By    y.A_YEAR, i.ID
--
--      R e s u l t :
--      A_YEAR ITEM_ID   ITEM_EVENTS_PER_YEAR
--  ---------- --------- --------------------
--        2000 2000_1                       2
--        2001 2000_2                       1
--        2001 2001_1                       2
--        2002 2001_2                       1
--        2002 2002_1                       1
--        2003 2001_3                       1
--        2003 2002_2                       2
--        2004 2002_3                       1
```